# Nginx - Files without .php are not reachable

Tags: php, nginx

I don't know why my pages are not eachable without .php extension. Something is wrong ? However it work on another of my website

When I put `try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html $uri.php?$query_string;` it's ok for the .php files without extension, but my website create "fakes folders/pages" like mywebsite.lol/category/example - and now it's doesn't reachable (404)

Here is my `server{}` block configuration.

```
# Gestion www
server {
    # Port
    listen 80;
    # Hostname
    server_name test.mywebsite.lol;
    # Logs
    access_log /var/log/nginx/test.mywebsite.lol.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/test.mywebsite.lol.error.log;
    root /home/mywebsite/www/test;
    # Fichier a executer par defaut (en ordre)
    index index.html index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on the php-fpm socket
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your log? `tail -t /var/log/nginx/error.log`

Comment: I have nothing... And when I try to go in a page I'm just redirect on the index page

Comment: Il doit y avoir une erreur. Just check your log files. What server are you using?

Comment: Certainement :p Debian 7, VPS (ovh). Nothing on error.log or test.mywebsite.error.lol.log :/ - I don't know why I'm redirected http://lght.pics/d1Z

Comment: What if you tried this http://pastebin.com/HeyhURbU

Comment: Maybe it is SELinux problem. Have you tried with `setenforce 0`?

Comment: Not really, I don't know what it is :/

Comment: With your server{} configuration, what does it show you if you want to access `http://test.mywebsite.lol/index.php` I am assuming you have an `index.php` at `/home/mywebsite/www/test/index.php`

Comment: It works. Work too with the others pages.php

Comment: Maybe comment the try_files as `# try_files $uri =404;` and try again. Make sure to refresh nginx, whenever you modify something from the config file

Comment: Well, sorry. You should have gotten an error in `/var/log/nginx/error.log` or `error_log /var/log/nginx/test.mywebsite.lol.error.log` so, I don't know why you are not getting any.

Comment: Really nothing in the error logs... thank you for your help.  I will try some things

Comment: What you are doing is very unnecessary if you do `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;` and You have `index.php` in `/home/mywebsite/www/test/` it's enough. You can then go to http://your-host/foo/bar/dasdas easily

Comment: Weird, when I try to go to test.mywebsite.lol/random I'm redirected to the index too, it's not normal I think ?

Comment: You don't understand how url rewriting works. Only index will be shown. You are trying to views folder, which I don't think is possible with your current config